# Query for field in subdocument

Tags: mongodb

An example of the schema i have;

```
{ "_id" : 1234,
  “dealershipName”: “Eric’s Mongo Cars”,
  “cars”: [
         {“year”: 2013,
           “make”: “10gen”,
           “model”: “MongoCar”,
           “vin”: 3928056,
           “mechanicNotes”: “Runs great!”},
         {“year”: 1985,
          “make”: “DeLorean”,
          “model”: “DMC-12”,
          “vin”: 8056309,
          “mechanicNotes”: “Great Scott!”}
         ]
  }
```

I wish to query and return only the value "vin" in "_id : 1234". Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: `_id:1234` contains two cars with different `vin`s. What exactly do you need as a result? An array like `[3928056, 8056309]`? Concrete examples are always helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming you want the `_id` AND the `vin` fields, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the field selection parameter with dot notation to constrain the output to just the desired field:

```javascript
db.test.find({_id: 1234}, {_id: 0, 'cars.vin': 1})
```

Output:

```javascript
{
    "cars" : [ 
        {
            "vin" : 3928056
        }, 
        {
            "vin" : 8056309
        }
    ]
}
```

Or if you just want an array of `vin` values you can use aggregate:

```javascript
db.test.aggregate([
    // Find the matching doc
    {$match: {_id: 1234}},
    // Duplicate it, once per cars element
    {$unwind: '$cars'},
    // Group it back together, adding each cars.vin value as an element of a vin array
    {$group: {_id: '$_id', vin: {$push: '$cars.vin'}}},
    // Only include the vin field in the output
    {$project: {_id: 0, vin: 1}}
])
```

Output:

```javascript
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "vin" : [ 
                3928056, 
                8056309
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Just to add to this answer, the projection part of the query (`{'cars.vin': 1}`) comes with the `_id` by defualt.  You can remove it if you do this: `{vin: true, _id: false}`  The values for the projection just go off of JS's truthy/ falsy values.

Comment: Right, I was just making that change.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Awesome, is there an easy way to filter the results by subdocument?

Comment: @StephenP. The easiest way to filter by subdoc is to add a `$match` between the `$unwind` and `$group`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

If by query, you mean get the values of the vins in javascript, you could read the json into a string called theString (or any other name) and do something like:

> var f = [], obj = JSON.parse(theString);
>
> obj.cars.forEach(function(item) { f.push(item.vin) });

If your json above is part of a larger collection, then you'd need an outer loop.